# crashlyticsUploadSymbols with muti apk build_code error

Tags: google-fabric, abi

As GooglePlay need 64 bit apk support from 8/1/2019, i Support different CPU architectures with each APK.
For details:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit
https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

I followed https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html configure to Build multiple APKs.

So now if armeabi's build_version is 1000, my arm64-v8a's build_version is 1001.

After ./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsapkxxx

But i found the Build_version all of armeabi and arm64-v8a are 1000.
So I think it's a error ?

Other Info:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Build multiple APKs configure :

```
// Map for the version code that gives each ABI a value.
ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi':0, 'arm64-v8a':1]
import com.android.build.OutputFile
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def baseAbiVersionCode = 
            project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))
    if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
      output.versionCodeOverride =
              baseAbiVersionCode * 1 + variant.versionCode
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the error that you get from Crashlytics? And have you tried upgrading your version of the Fabric Gradle plugin? 1.27.1 is fairly out of date: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin